# How to get file + line info debug info in Linux mono's assembly

Tags: mono, debian

I have an abnormal exception in a Linux mono assembly.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ObjectDisposedException: The object was used after being disposed.
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ReceiveAsync (System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at cloudBus.TCPConnection.Receive () [0x0003d] in /home/xyz/cloudBus/TCPServer.cs:26
...
```

I want to get line number and filename for ReceiveAsync.
I did compile in with -debug flag and execute with --debug.
I also get full mono from Git and recompile it but I can't get debug info.

What option to use to get the exception line info? I think this is mono make option but can't find it.

When found I'll try to fix this bug, only reproductible on Linux, and report correction.

Answer (score 0):

You could [build Mono from source](http://mono-project.com/Compiling_Mono_From_Git), if you want to track this problem on git HEAD version.

On the other hand, Debian should have debug/development versions of Mono available as well, that will give you debugging info for your installed version.

Answer (score 0):

I have found.

To build framework with debug info, in the file mono/mcs/build/config.make

add the line

MCS_FLAGS = -debug

Answer (score 0):

On Debian the package mono-dbg provides debugging information for System.*. For your own code have a look at [mono debug information with exceptions on debian?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317343/mono-debug-information-with-exceptions-on-debian) .